# Why to override hashCode and equals methods in hibernate persistence class?

Tags: java, hibernate

Why is it considered the best practice to override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods in a Hibernate persistence class?

Comment: Please provide a reference to who says it's a best practice.

Comment: the code quality tools like SONAR,CAST

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate doc:

> You have to override the equals() and hashCode() methods if you
>
> intend to put instances of persistent classes in a Set (the
>   recommended way to represent many-valued associations) and
>
> intend to use reattachment of detached instances
>
> Hibernate guarantees equivalence of persistent identity (database row)
>   and Java identity only inside a particular session scope. So as soon
>   as we mix instances retrieved in different sessions, we must implement
>   equals() and hashCode() if we wish to have meaningful semantics for
>   Sets.

see this link https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html

Let's consider this scenario to show some of the problems that will occurs if you are using the default implementation of equals and hashcode:

```
@Entity Parent{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        Long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",
         cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
        Set<Child> childrens = new HashSet<Child>();
        //get+set
        }

@Entity Child{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        Long id;
        }
```

---

```
    test(){
          Parent p1 = new Parent();
          Child c1 = new Child();
          entityManager.persist(p1);
          entityManager.persist(c1);
          p1.getChilds.add(c1);
          entityManager.merge(p);
          //!!:using another instance of entitymanager just to simulate the case of detached entities.
          Parent p2 =entityManager1.find(p1.getId(),Parent.class);
          child c2 =entityManager1.find(c1.getId(),Child.class);
          boolean contains=p1.getChilds().contains(c2); // problem1: contains==false
          //Then if we add c2 to the childs set we will have 
          //a duplication inside the Set
          p2.getChilds.add(c2);//problem2:childs contains c1 and c2
          boolean remove=p2.getChilds.remove(c2);//problem3:remove==false
          entityManager1.merge(p2);//problem4: hibernate will deal with c2
          //like a new entity then an insert operation is 
          //triggered on c2 (an exception=> violation of unique id)
        }
```

Comment: so,hashcode() and equals() should be implemented in both entity classes which has one to many relationships where setting a child entity can cause detached instances??

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutly no reason to override `equals` and `hashCode` because `Hibernate` do not rely on them. It compares entities themself by comparing attributes.

Comment: Hibernate documentation states otherwise, that you should implement equals() and hashCode() if an entity will be put in a collection that makes use of those methods and if you plan to reattach dettached instances.